# Key Value Observing with an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I've looked on SO for examples of using Key Value Observing with an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) and apparently you need to use an `NSArrayController` (which unlike `KVO` I'm not familiar with), but I haven't found concrete examples of how to do this. Can anyone explain with some sample code?

For instance, if I have a `GameModel` which represents its player names with an `NSArray (playerNameArray)` of `NSStrings`. I want to observe those strings (the view controller observes the model's data) to update various things in the view.

How do I get notification that the player name array has changed?

**EDIT**: Does the iOS SDK even support `NSArrayController`? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need an NSArrayController to observe changes to an `NSArray`. However you cannot directly observe these changes, i.e., you can't call `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` directly on an `NSArray`. In your case you want to call it on your `GameModel` with `@"playerNameArray"` as the key.

You're not done yet though. The normal automatic KVO notifications will only kick in if you call `-setPlayerNameArray:`, thereby replacing the entire array. If you want more granular notifications, then you need to use `-willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` and `-didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` whenever you insert, remove, or replace items in that array.

This will send a notification whenever the contents of the array changes. Depending on the `NSKeyValueObservingOptions` you use when adding your observer, you can also get the incremental changes that are made—a cool feature, but you may not need it in this case.

Note: NSArrayController does not exist on iOS. It's part of Cocoa Bindings, which currently only exists in AppKit on Mac OS X. Luckily, you don't need it.

Comment: I tried precisely this setup on iOS-4, and nothing happened (both callbacks implemented, via Xcode autocomplete, so I'm sure they're typed correctly. I checked all objects involved are non-null, everything checked again with breakpoints). Has Apple removed it?

Comment: They're not callbacks - you have to call them in order to get regular KVO on a collection to work.

Comment: @Adam what he's saying is that you have to write your own accessors for the NSMutableArray and fire the KVO notes yourself.

Comment: Yeah that little detail wasn't exactly clear in the 4 paragraph answer above :/