# KVO and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

How can I set KVO (key-value-observing) with an `NSMutableArray`?

I want to be notified when a change appears in the array. I never used KVO before with a collection like an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you'll be interested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477204/key-value-observing-a-to-many-relationship-in-cocoa).

The key is that you can't observe any properties on the array directly—the array is just storage—but you *can* observe the to-many relationship that's backed by that array (here I'm assuming your array is a property on an object somewhere).

If you don't want to use those special accessors all over the place, your code that owns the array can call

`-willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` and

`-didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478451/key-value-observing-with-an-nsarray/3479097#3479097).

And if you're on a Mac and not iOS, you should consider `NSArrayController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KVOMutableArray](https://github.com/haifengkao/KVOMutableArray).
It is a subclass of NSMutableArray, and it supports KVO.

disclaimer: I am the author :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really want to downvote—but I'm questioning the quality of the linked library. At best, it could be described as an observable container implementation. What it is not is **a KVO compliant NSMutableArray**. @JoeOsborn describes in the other answer this is a misunderstanding of the KVO concept: KVO needs an observable *key*, which can be used to form *key paths* through the object hierarchy. Cocoa has no way of addressing collection objects themselves using a key.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yes, it is an observable container implementation and the container happens to be a subclass of NSMutableArray. The original question asks for a way to monitor the changes of array. It indeed provides a way to do it. It does use a observable key, which is "observer.arr". I believe we are on the same page.