# Simple Query: How does one detect the addition of an item in a mutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KVO and NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914248/kvo-and-nsmutablearray)

Like the title says, I need to be able to detect a change in a mutable array. The reason for this would be to automatically refresh my mapview for an app I'm making as soon as the user adds a new location.

I imagine it would be something like asking if the array is equal to the array's count plus one or the array's count minus one but I don't know how to implement that.

If you need more information before answering please don't hesitate to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Observing for this. For more details check [Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

> Key-value observing provides a mechanism that allows objects to be
>   notified of changes to specific properties of other objects. It is
>   particularly useful for communication between model and controller
>   layers in an application. (In OS X, the controller layer binding
>   technology relies heavily on key-value observing.) A controller object
>   typically observes properties of model objects, and a view object
>   observes properties of model objects through a controller. In
>   addition, however, a model object may observe other model objects
>   (usually to determine when a dependent value changes) or even itself
>   (again to determine when a dependent value changes).
>
> You can observe properties including simple attributes, to-one
>   relationships, and to-many relationships. Observers of to-many
>   relationships are informed of the type of change made—as well as which
>   objects are involved in the change.

Check [this blog](http://blog.herlein.com/2012/01/simple-ios-key-value-observing-kvo-explained/) about KVO on how to use it. Also [check this tutorial.](http://nachbaur.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-kvo) Check this question as well, [Key-Value-Observing a to-many relationship in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477204/key-value-observing-a-to-many-relationship-in-cocoa)

Comment: Thank you, I think this answers my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to this question.

A popular way would be to use NSNotficationCenter to post notifications everytime your model changes.

You can also use delegation to invoke a method when an object is inserted or Key-Value Observing.

It much depends on your design. If you specify, maybe you can get a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use KVO for that. Personally I don't like NotificationCenter but I guess that personal taste.

see [KVO and NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914248/kvo-and-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution would be Don't Do That. If you the one making the change to the mutable array, then you know you are making a change to the mutable array. If you aren't, then don't vend a mutable array; wrap the array in a class so that any changes must come in through a method that you control.